# Remove duplicate values within a list and outside the list using python

Tags: python, list

For example :

If I have three lists like

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [2,3]
l3 = [1,4]
```

these three list are my inputs,

My expected output to be like

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [3]
l3 = [4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [2,3]
l3 = [1,4]
l1s = set(l1)
l2s = set(l2)
l3s = set(l3)

print(list(l1),list(l2s-l1s),list(l3s-(l1s.union(l2s))))
```

**output**

```
[1, 2] [3] [4]
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension that removes duplicates within the list by converting to a set, and duplicates between the lists by checking each element explicitly:

```
l1 = list(set(l1))
l2 = [x for x in set(l2) if not x in l1]
l3 = [x for x in set(l3) if not x in l1 and not x in l2]
```

**Edit**: Since you asked for a one-liner (why?!), here is one - with some explanation in comments:

```
print [[element for n, element in enumerate(sublist) if n == sublist.index(element) and not element in list(chain(*lists[:sublistIndex]))] for sublistIndex, sublist in enumerate(lists)]
"""
        \-------------------------------------------------------------------------/     \-------------------------------------------------/
          use this element if it's that value's first occurrence in the sublist...      and it doesn't occur in the joined earlier sublists                                
"""
```

*It's ugly, long, inefficient, and I strongly recommend against it, but it's possible*!

If you use this with `lists = [[3, 1, 1], [2, 4, 3], [3, 4, 5]]`, you'll get the correct output

```
[[3, 1], [2, 4], [5]]
```

Preserving the original order, too.

Comment: Is it possible to do this within a single line code?The expected output may also be like a list inside list example: [[1,2],[3],[4]]

Comment: This won't preserve the original list order of course, not sure if that is important

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a set in which all the elements are saved. If an element isn't already in the set, add it to the set and the current list. Both alternatives work for any number of elements and lists, and keep the original order :

## With a function and list comprehensions :

```
my_lists = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [1, 4]
]


def is_new_element(element, my_set):
    if element in my_set:
        return False
    else:
        my_set.add(element)
        return True

already_seen = set()
print([[x for x in l if is_new_element(x, already_seen)] for l in my_lists])
# [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
```

## With double loops :

It's a bit verbose but it doesn't require any new function :

```
my_lists = [
        [1,2],
        [2,3],
        [1,4]
    ]   

uniq_lists = []
already_seen = set()

for lst in my_lists:
    uniq_list = []
    for element in lst:
        if element not in already_seen:
            already_seen.add(element)
            uniq_list.append(element)
    uniq_lists.append(uniq_list)

print(uniq_lists)
# [[1, 2], [3], [4]]
```